# Sending actions to a component with Ember.js 1.13

Tags: ember.js

I have an audio-player Ember.js component which I'd like to send events to from anywhere:

`this.get('audioPlayer').send('play');`

To get access to the component, I set the component as a property on itself which exposes it to the controller ([link](http://www.samselikoff.com/blog/getting-ember-components-to-respond-to-actions/)).

- Working example Ember 1.12: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/wokelikice/1/edit
- Failing example Ember 1.13: http://jsbin.com/yaporapuwu/2/edit

This stopped working in Ember 1.13-beta and I thought I must be doing it wrong. Data down, actions up and all.

How would you architect an application with a global audio-player?
And how would you send actions on a component? (or is there a better way?)

Comment: Might be a bug. Glimmer engine has introduced some regression. Try searching the issue list to see if this is already reported. Or report this as a bug.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it working in 1.13 like so: http://jsbin.com/serunaxozi/1/edit

The only change is modifying the `_register` method as follows:

```
_register: function() {
    this.get('attrs.register-as.update')(this);
}.on('init')
```

1.13 is making changes to the way components reference attributes. Attributes on the components are accessed through the `attrs` object to differentiate them from component variables. They also have `value` and `update` properties to make due for implicit one-way binding with two-way binding via the `mut` keyword.

Remember this is still work-in-progress, so right now we need to manually get the `update` method from the attribute and invoke it, but I'd imagine in future this will be done using a setter as follows:

```
this.set('attrs.register-as', this);
```

Also bear in mind that eventually components will be used with angle-brackets, and you would need to specifically say that an attribute is a two-way binding for Ember to generate that update method:

```
<audio-player title="Michael Jackson" test={{test}} register-as={{mut audioPlayer}} />
```

This is still a little buggy at the moment (using the angle-bracket syntax, `attrs` is not available in the method which is run with `on('init')`).

-- Edit--

Attributes will not be available inside `init` in the future and will instead have another hook `didInitAttrs`. See https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/11200.

Comment: Does this mean we have to null/undefined check all data up actions that are optional? `if (this.attrs.optionalAction) { this.attrs.optionalAction(this.get('data')); }`

Comment: If it's optional, you should check for existence (`Ember.isPresent`). If it's not optional, let it break.